# Story ident : Man investigates teen ESP

Tags: story-identification, books, powers

It starts off with a research campus thing run by a man investigating the supernatural abilities. He gatherss group of teens all of whom have a special ability (I can't recall exactly what) and they become close friends.

It's revealed the experiments used on the kids to find out the length of their abilities was used so eventually the guy in charge could use them for himself. I remember one of the boys could read thoughts and the main character (female) had something particular about her six senses(?)

The most vivid part I remember is when she was locked and bound in a soundproof room so she can't see hear feel or connect with the others because the guy is trying to take them down.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like it could be the [**Dark Visions Trilogy**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Visions_Trilogy), written by L.J. Smith.

The three books in the series are **The Strange Power** (1994), **The Possessed** (1995), and **The Passion** (1995), though they were also published as a single volume (aka an omnibus) in 2009. According to the wiki, the authot is writing a sequel to the series titled **Blindsight**.

#### Basic plot summary

> The story follows the protagonist, Kaitlyn Fairchild, as she attends,
> uncovers a plot, and ultimately defeats the Zetes Institute, a place
> where she went to learn about her own psychic powers. Kait and the
> four other psychics at the live-in Zetes Institute are the most
> powerful psychics in the country in their age group. They come from
> all areas of the U.S. and become best of friends.

---

#### The teens:

**Kaitlyn Brady Fairchild**, known as Kait, is the 17 year old protagonist of the series. Her psychic talent is that she (usually subconsciously) creates drawings that are premonitions. Her inability to understand the drawings until too late drives her to attend the Zetes Institute.

**Rob Kessler** (also seventeen) is a North Carolina native and another attendee of the Zetes Institute. His power is the ability to heal by manipulating life energy

**Gabriel Wolfe** (also seventeen) is the ambiguous character that eventually joins the light side. He comes to the Zetes Institute from jail, having previously killed by accident and in self-defense. He is a telepath, and when he uses his power on minds that are weaker than his, he drains those people of their life energy.

**Anna Eva Whiteraven** (also seventeen) is the only other girl at the Zetes Institute and is from Washington State. She is Native American and described as having long black hair. She is very peaceful and gentle girl who becomes Kait's roommate at the Institute. Her psychic abilities allow her to communicate with animals and control them.

**Lewis Chao** (also seventeen) is from San Francisco and is the last of the group at the Zetes Institute. He is Asian-American and described to be friendly and obsessed with technology. He has the ability of psychokinesis, the ability to move (small) objects with his mind; later he uses his abilities to jam radio frequencies, set off telephones, even open hidden doors.

---

#### The Evil Plot:

From **Strange Power** (Book 1):

> While at the Institute, they are tested on their psychic abilities,
> but a mysterious man warns Kaitlyn that the Institute is dangerous,
> and even the sullen housekeeper Marisol warns them to get out as soon
> as possible, after which she goes into coma. The psychics become
> suspicious and begin to believe the warnings about the Institute. They
> investigate and find a secret passageway, which contains plans to turn
> them into psychic weapons to sell to major corporations, and a file
> about Project Black Lightning, a previous project in which other
> psychics were tested upon and 'terminated'. The teens almost get
> caught by the head of the Institute, Mr. Zetes, and Gabriel locks the
> five of them into a psychic link to save them. The link allows them to
> 'hear' each other's thoughts and communicate, but they cannot get rid
> of it afterwards so they try to find a way to break the link, but
> discover that the only way is for one of them to die. Eventually, Mr.
> Zetes talks to Gabriel and invites him to his mansion to discuss his
> future, as he believes Gabriel is ready to join him in his plans to
> create psychic weapons. Kaitlyn overhears the conversation and offers
> to join too, so she can find out the what is really happening. At the
> mansion, Mr. Zetes shows them a giant crystal that will make them
> powerful weapons by amplifying their psychic powers but he admits that
> it can warp minds and make them evil, as he found out with 'Project
> Black Lightning'

About the villain:

> Emmanuel Zetes is the villain of the story. He is very wealthy and
> founded the Zetes Institute for research on psychic phenomena.
> However, it is revealed that the Institute is actually preparing
> psychics to perform as a special for-hire task force for criminal
> activities. He is the owner of a "firestone" or "great crystal", which
> can store and enhance psychic energy.

---

#### Locked and bound in a soundproof room

From **The Passion** (Book 3):

> Kaitlyn is eventually caught by Mr Zetes when she cracks the code for
> the location of the crystal, and he puts her in an isolation tank,
> where he hopes she will be driven to insanity. Gabriel becomes worried
> about Kaitlyn when he can no longer feel her presence in the psychic
> link and he reaches out for her with his telepathy. He helps her
> preserve her mind by showing her memories and communicating with her,
> and they both confess their true depths of feelings for each other.
> When Mr Zetes takes Kaitlyn out the isolation tank, he realises his
> plan has not worked and he takes Kaitlyn to the crystal to destroy her
> mind. Rob, Anna, Lewis and Tamsin from the fellowship of the crystal,
> turn up to rescue them, and they succeed in destroying the crystal and
> Mr Zetes when Gabriel unites the shard with the evil crystal. When the
> crystal is shattered, Joyce's mind and the other psychic's minds are
> returned to them, and they realise the mistakes they made in joining
> Mr Zetes.